# I have vectors over a finite field GF(p) where p is power of a prime. How are all the different ways in which I can define the length of a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

I have vectors over a finite field GF(p) where p is power of a prime.  What are all the different ways in which I can define the length of a vector?

Comment: Depends on what you want the length to satisfy. For most natural requirements, there are no ways to do it.

Comment: I would guess there are some "natural" properties it should satisfy.  The length should be 0 iff if the vector is 0.  It should also satisfy the triangle property.

Comment: I assume by the triangle property you mean $|a+b|\leq |a| + |b|$. With no further restrictions, you can for example just define the length to be $1$ unless the vector is $0$.

Comment: No one uses the symbol $p$ to stand for a power of a prime. It's a bit like using $\pi$ to stand for the ratio between the circumference and radius of a circle.

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft:That satisfies and that is a good example.  I am wondering whether there are infinite such definitions that satisfy or there are only finite such definitions.